# flashing twrp on lg g4 no error, but no twrp

Tags: fastboot, twrp, lg, lg-g4

I'm trying to flash twrp to my lg g4. I've reached the part where I run

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
```

And everything seems to work fine, but when I try to enter recovery mode, I get the default lg recovery (restore factory mode options) and not twrp.
Here's what it prints out when I run the flash command:

```
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (32060 KB)...  
OKAY [  0.827s]  
writing 'recovery'...  
OKAY [  0.341s]  
finished. total time: 1.168s
```

What am I doing wrong?
I tried doing it from a different computer and tried flashing older version of twrp.

Comment: After flashing that recovery, did you boot straight into recovery mode or into Android first? Your Android may be having a setting under Developer options to revert the recovery back to stock. Even if it is not, try executing this: `fastboot boot twrp.img`. If that doesn't work either, try flashing recovery as you did but boot straight into recovery mode. This would mean that you've to exit from fastboot mode by long-pressing power button and then use recovery specific button combination to boot.

Comment: Thank you! Running `fastboot boot twrp.img` worked :)

Comment: But the results are temporary, so it is better to find the issue. Boot into Android OS, go into Developer options and tell us whether you see any entry related to recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue..
Apparently, when you enter recovery mode, the phone asks you whether you'd like to do a factory reset, and you choose `yes` it boots into TWRP :)
Hope it helps someone.