# Unable to flash TWRP on a LG G4 (LG H815)

Tags: rooting, twrp, lg-g4

I own an international LG G4 LG H815 and running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. For the whole day I am unable to flash TWRP on the phone. First I unlocked the bootloader with succes. Now I am trying to flash TWRP on the phone, commands that I used are :

```
mark@Mark-PC:~/Bureaublad/LG_G4_unlock/Root$ adb reboot bootloader
@Mark-PC:~/Bureaublad/LG_G4_unlock/Root$ sudo fastboot flash recovery twrp-2.8.6.0-hima.img 
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (35928 KB)...
OKAY [  1.440s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.353s]
finished. total time: 1.793s
```

After flashing I immidiately turned of the phone by pulling out the battery to prevent normal booting. Every time I boot in the normal stock recovery that offers my to perform a factory reset.

I was reading the question [flashing twrp on lg g4 no error, but no twrp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133490/flashing-twrp-on-lg-g4-no-error-but-no-twrp) but tries were also not succesfull. Chosing yes in the stock recovery wiped the data instead of booting to TWRP. I tried the same with different versions of TWRP for the LG H815 and of them gave the same result. My LG G4 is running Android 5.1 stock ROM without root.

I was also unable to find a file to flash by using fastboot that offers root access to flash a recovery from Android. All of the methods to root requires a working TWRP recovery.

```
mark@Mark-PC:~/Bureaublad/LG_G4_unlock/Root$ sudo fastboot boot twrp-2.8.6.0-hima.img
```

Booting of the image directly did also not work

I will be very happy when I am able to salve this problem.

Now I tried this manual on another Windows laptop : https://techbeasts.com/2015/06/16/install-twrp-recovery-on-lg-g4-root-it/

but after the commands

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot boot recovery.img
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.710s]
booting...
OKAY [  0.400s]
finished. total time: 1.117s
```

unfortunately it boots normal after 20 seconds and stays unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. The developers of TWRP switched the recoveries for the LG h811 and LG h815 model. So I downloaded and flashed a TWRP recovery under h811 downloads and that recovery works properly on my LG h815.

Comment: I can confirm you here, following your answer, I downloaded h811, and other than the h815 TWRP which just crashed, my h815 device runs fine with the h811 image.