# Why my LG G4 cannot boot or use TWRP custom recovery but cyanogenrecovery without problems?

Tags: cyanogenmod, twrp, lg-g4

For several days I am trying to get TWRP custom recovery on my LG G4 h815 International. Currently the phone is unlocked and has Cyanogenmod 13 and cyanogenrecovery but without google gapps. I really want to have google gapps on the ROM but I am unable to flash with cyanogenrecovery [Unable to flash gapps via cyanogenrecovery on a LG G4 (LG h815 Int)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136275/unable-to-flash-gapps-via-cyanogenrecovery-on-a-lg-g4-lg-h815-int). Therefore I want to replace cyanogenrecovery by TWRP recovery.

When I do **fastboot boot twrp-3.0.0-0-h815.img**, the phone boots normally.

When I do **fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.0.0-0-h815.img** a get no error and successfully flash but I cannot boot into recovery.

When I do **fastboot boot cm-13.0-20160209-NIGHTLY-h815-recovery.img**, the phone boots correctly into cyanogenrecovery but this recovery gives an error 70 when flashing gapps.
Flashing cm-13.0-20160209-NIGHTLY-h815-recovery.img is also successful and I can successfully boot into cyanogenrecovery.

For all nightlies of cyanogenrecovery I am able to boot in recovery and/or flash but all of them gives error 70.
For all of the 4 versions of TWRP https://dl.twrp.me/h815/ I cannot boot into them by using fastboot. Flashing al of them results to that I am completely unable to boot into recovery (also no cyanogenrecovery anomore).

Also I unchecked update cyanogenrecovery in developer options.

When flashing TWRP with flashify there is no error but also no boot into TWRP. Flasing cyanogenrecovery in flashify gives also no error and booting properly in that recovery.

Does anybody knows why I can boot into cyanogenrecovery without problems but booting into any version of TWRP seems to be impossible. I have the idea that my phone doesn't accept a TWRP recovery because of cyanogenrecovery boots without any problems after flashing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got TWRP on my LG G4 h815. The problem was that I had to use the TWRP version of the LG h811 instead of h815. The developers of TWRP put recoveries for the h815 under h811 downloads and recoveries for h811 under downloads for h815.